# Fill div the remaining height of the screen, without overflow (ie scrolling)

Tags: html, css, three.js

I am in the process of starting a WebGL project and have created a functional NavBar at the top using Bootstrap 5. I am trying to fill the remaining space with a canvas where I will be rendering my work. However using `height: 100%;`, to my guess seems to be trying height to not be including the NavBar and is going too far below the screen creating a scrolling wheel.

I am creating a working example shown here https://jsfiddle.net/cL40tzg9/6/ that will show what I mean. I am simply trying to create a NavBar and will the remaining space with my canvas, preventing any unwanted scrolling. What have I done wrong here? Thanks

The JavaScript is (minified a little),

```css
/* with the CSS being: */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#scene_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand h1" style="cursor: default"> example </a>
  </div>
</nav>

<canvas id="scene_container"> </canvas>
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question rather than as a link to an external resource

Comment: The canvas cannot be 100% as the `nav` also occupies space. Perhaps a `flexbox` approach would suit?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius would I be nesting both the `navbar` and `scene` in the single `flexbox`?

Comment: You could do - the `body` might be a suitable flex container

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius what properties should I be looking at for the `flexbox` to solve my issue? Suppose I nest both items inside a `class="flex-container"` and then have ```.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}``` which property should I be looking at?

Answer (score 2):

A simple Flex approach to set the canvas to the full height minus the nav height might look a little like this. The following uses a css var `--nav-height` for convenience and background colours applied to illustrate the effect.

```css
:root{
  --nav-height:3rem;
}
html, body {
    height:100vh;
    max-height:100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}


body,body *{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
}

body{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

nav{
  height:var(--nav-height);
  min-height:var(--nav-height);
  max-height:var(--nav-height);
  width:100%;
  flex:1;
  
  background:yellow;
}

canvas{
  width:100%;
  height:calc( 100vh - var(--nav-height) );
  flex:100;
  
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<nav class='navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light'>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <a class='navbar-brand h1' style='cursor: default'> example </a>
  </div>
</nav>
<canvas id='scene_container'></canvas>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work for me, and I am receiving no errors in my console. I still receive a large scroll wheel because my canvas is growing too large.

Comment: Are you viewing on a mobile device? On my laptop this seems fine

Comment: I am using a desktop :( 
Still seems to be occupying a lot of height.

Comment: The scrollwheel of the width got removed, but the height that it allows you to scroll down is the height of the navbar.

Answer (score 0):

you either need to use `flex` or deduct the height of `nav` from `canvas`, if `nav` has static height.

```
#scene_container {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100% - 64px);
    background: transparent;
    z-index: 0; 
}
```

**64px** is your current nav height.

Comment: Wouldn't the nav height change between devices? I usually try to avoid hard coded differences.

Comment: depends how you design your website, you can make it static or change it on different screen sizes. but you can change the `hight` via `media queries` in different sizes also.
I'd recommend using `flex` if possible.